# PHP prepend leading zero before single digit number, on-the-fly

Tags: php, string, numbers, zero

PHP - Is there a quick, on-the-fly method to test for a single character string, then prepend a leading zero?

Example:

```
$year = 11;
$month = 4;

$stamp = $year.add_single_zero_if_needed($month);  // Imaginary function

echo $stamp; // 1104
```

Comment: After testing, turns out sprintf() was a bit better: it has a common language format and doesn't use a class constant, among other things.

Answer (score 615, accepted):

You can use sprintf: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
<?php
$num = 4;
$num_padded = sprintf("%02d", $num);
echo $num_padded; // returns 04
?>
```

It will only add the zero if it's less than the required number of characters.

**Edit: As pointed out by @FelipeAls:**

When working with numbers, you should use `%d` (rather than `%s`), especially when there is the potential for negative numbers. If you're only using positive numbers, either option works fine.

For example:

`sprintf("%04s", 10);` returns 0010
`sprintf("%04s", -10);` returns 0-10

Where as:

`sprintf("%04d", 10);` returns  0010
`sprintf("%04d", -10);` returns -010

Comment: Beware of negative numbers (obviously not a problem with dates here! :) ). `%03s` can output `0-5` where `%03d` would output `-05`

Comment: this doesn't work with negative numbers

Comment: @RafikBari I've updated my answer to include the information @FelipeAls mentioned. Negative numbers are handled fine, provided you use `%02d`.

Comment: Your edit is wrong, sprintf("%04s", 10); returns 0010, not 1000.

Comment: Also sprintf("%04d", -10); returns -010. Tested on PHP 5.5.18

Comment: Can this be reversed?

Answer (score 231):

You can use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) for adding 0's

```
str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string = " " [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]] )`

Comment: Pure gold right here!

Comment: @zzlalani - actually if you look carefully at the example in Kirk Beard's answer, it is saved to a variable :)

Comment: this doesn't work with negative nums

Answer (score 18):

The universal tool for string formatting, `sprintf`:

```
$stamp = sprintf('%s%02s', $year, $month);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: str_pad is more readable. I like keeping things simple. sprintf is great function, i use it a lot for transaltions, when there must be a variable in the middle of the string, but for such thing, i will go with str_pad(); while i'm working only with positive integers. they don't require any fancy stuff.

Comment: Use sprintf:

sprintf('%08d', 1234567);

Alternatively you can also use str_pad:

str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: what about signed digit ? str_replace("00", "0", sprintf('%03d', $num))