# Prepend leading zero before positive or negative single digit number

Tags: php

I tried the accepted answer which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659042/php-prepend-leading-zero-before-single-digit-number-on-the-fly) but the accepted answer does not add leading zero if number is like -9, -8, -7 etc.

I want to append a zero if a number is single digit in both cases if positive or negative like,

```
+9 => +09
-9 => -09
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could check the length of the variable and the first character, if the length is 1 add a leading 0, if the length is 2 and the first character is -, add a 0 in the middle

Comment: assume this number 50, its length is also 2 so it will add the 0 before 50 and it will become 050 which i don't want. As i only want to append zero on a single digit number

Comment: if the length is 2 AND the first character is -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo sprintf('%+03d', $number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
function addZero($number)

   switch(strLen($number)) {

      case 1:
          return "0" . $number;
          break;

      case 2:
          if (substr($number, 0) == "-") return "-0" . substr($number, 1);
          break;

   }

   return $number

}
```