# PHP adding zeros to numbers

Tags: php, string, numbers

Im trying to generate barcode and i need it to be in 20 numbers. Barcode requires that reference must be in 20 numbers.

So if my reference is 67585
its must be 20 numbers like that 00000000000000067585

And if reference is 489382995463342
Barcode number must be in 20 numbers like 00000489382995463342

I tried this code but it's not working properly

```
str_pad(str_replace('', '',$reference), 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: why it's not working? apart from the useless str_replace, it looks fine

Comment: I tested this and it works. Like the previous commenter says, not sure what the str_replace is for.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? What gives str_pad back on your server?

Comment: it was given me just 18 numbers, weard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
str_pad($reference, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

OR,

```
sprintf('%20d', $reference);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine (see http://3v4l.org/UKBqS), how are you viewing/inspecting the final value?

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('PHP_EOL')) {
    define('PHP_EOL', "\n");
}

foreach (array('67585', '489382995463342') as $test) {
    echo str_pad($test, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sprintf`

Docs Link for sprintf function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
<?php
$num = 4;
$num_padded = sprintf("%02s", $num);
echo $num_padded; // returns 04
?>
```

[PHP prepend leading zero before single digit number, on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659042/php-prepend-leading-zero-before-single-digit-number-on-the-fly)