# Forcing to Push Number to Array in 2 Digits Format For Less than 10

Tags: php

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can I insert two digits format (even for the numbers less than 10) like `01, 02, 03,..., 09` into the array `$days`

```
$days = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    array_push($days, $i);
} 
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r ($days);
 echo '</pre>';
```

the out put looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 17
    [17] => 18
    [18] => 19
    [19] => 20
    [20] => 21
    [21] => 22
    [22] => 23
    [23] => 24
    [24] => 25
    [25] => 26
    [26] => 27
    [27] => 28
    [28] => 29
    [29] => 30
)
```

but I need to ave like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 04
    [4] => 05
    [5] => 06
    [6] => 07
    [7] => 08
    [8] => 09
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 17
    [17] => 18
    [18] => 19
    [19] => 20
    [20] => 21
    [21] => 22
    [22] => 23
    [23] => 24
    [24] => 25
    [25] => 26
    [26] => 27
    [27] => 28
    [28] => 29
    [29] => 30
)
```

Comment: simply detect if the number is less than or equal to 9

Comment: use simple array_map and str_pad  try my answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP prepend leading zero before single digit number, on-the-fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659042/php-prepend-leading-zero-before-single-digit-number-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be somewhat like this

```
function zero_prefix($num)
{
     if($num <= 9)
     {
         return '0'.$num;
     }
     return $num;
}

$days = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $proper_format_number = zero_prefix($i);
    array_push($days, $proper_format_number );
} 
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($days);
echo '</pre>';
```

Results in the array you want

Comment: thanks immortal but this is loading only 0 into the all numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to format it as a fixed width string. The `%0` specifier is for padding (*the default pad is space*), so we add another `0` as the padding character, and specify a minimum width of `2`. Thus `sprintf("%002s", $i)` gives you `01`-`09` for numbers lower than 10 (*`s` being the string format specifier*).

```
$days = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $days[] = sprintf("%002s", $i);
} 

var_dump($days);
```

This gives you.

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "01"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "02"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "03"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "04"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "05"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "06"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "07"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "08"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "09"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [12]=>
  string(2) "13"
  [13]=>
  string(2) "14"
  [14]=>
  string(2) "15"
  [15]=>
  string(2) "16"
  [16]=>
  string(2) "17"
  [17]=>
  string(2) "18"
  [18]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [19]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [20]=>
  string(2) "21"
  [21]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [22]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [23]=>
  string(2) "24"
  [24]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [25]=>
  string(2) "26"
  [26]=>
  string(2) "27"
  [27]=>
  string(2) "28"
  [28]=>
  string(2) "29"
  [29]=>
  string(2) "30"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple  [array_map](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp)  and [str_pad](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp)

```
<?php

 $arr =range(1,30);

  $ss = array_map(function($item) {

     return str_pad($item, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 


  }, $arr);

  print_r($ss);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   Array
   (
     [0] => 01
     [1] => 02
     [2] => 03
     ........
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

hey @Suffii just make a condition like if $i>10 then just concat $i with 0 ,like following:

```
<?php 
$days = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    if($i<10){  
        $j=(0).($i);
    array_push($days,$j);
    }else{

    array_push($days,$i);
}
} 
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r ($days);
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is working example try it.