# Setting the leading zero in hours,minutes and seconds in php

Tags: php

I have a script which i want to use to generate some data from a certain date. The problem i am having is setting the leading zero for minutes,hours and seconds.

For instance

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){
    //echo $i.'<br/>';
    $start = "2012-10-01 $i:00:00";
    echo $start.'<br/>'; 
}
?>
```

I want all hours from 0 to 9 to have a leading zero. Is there a functions that can help me have the leading zero in hours,minutes or seconds?.

Comment: `$start = sprintf("2012-10-01 %02d:00:00", $i);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659042/php-prepend-leading-zero-before-single-digit-number-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str_pad`

```
for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){
    $temp = str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
    $start = "2012-10-01 $temp:00:00";
    echo $start.'<br/>'; 
}
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/8SV7uj)**