# PHP - convert 9 to 09 (the month of September)

Tags: php, date

Seems like this should be simple but I can't get it to work.

I have credit card expiration months in format n (without leading zeros) and need it to be m (with leading zeros)

How do I convert an n month to an m?

Comment: You've any code to share?

Comment: If your months run from 1 to 12 then simply check if the month is less than 10, if it is then put a 0 on the front by converting it to a string.

Comment: refer this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659042/php-prepend-leading-zero-before-single-digit-number-on-the-fly)

Comment: @Sachi.Dila  Thanks so much. Works like a charm.

$new_mo = str_pad($expire_mo, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sprintf function for this...

```
<?php
 $monthnumber = date('m');
 $month = sprintf('%02d', $monthnumber);
 echo $month;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to automatically pad a value to 2 (or more) characters with leading zeros:

```
echo sprintf("%02d", 9);
```

Output

```
09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10 because I'm fancy
    return i;
}
```